# How to execute multi window/tab TestCafe scripts on BrowserStack?

Tags: testcafe

We've automated multi tab/window scenarios using TestCafe scripts which can be run on local system without any issues. But we're getting the below error when we execute them on BrowserStack

**Errors**:

```
Multi-window mode is supported only in locally-installed Chrome, Chromium, Edge 84+ and Firefox. Run tests in these browsers to use the "openWindow" method

Multi-window mode is supported only in locally-installed Chrome, Chromium, Edge 84+ and Firefox. Run tests in these browsers to use the "getCurrentWindow" method
```

It's a limitation from TestCafe. Are there any alternates to execute these TestCafe scripts on BrowserStack ?

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe cannot run tests in multiple window mode in cloud/remote browsers.
This limitation is stated in the TestCafe documentation: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/intermediate-guides/multiple-browser-windows#limitations.